# Accessing Google Drive API from React Native using a Service Account

Tags: react-native, service-accounts, drive

I have a React Native application that needs to upload and download files on a single Google Drive space with 100GB (**not the user's one**)

I have followed google's documentation to:

- Setup my project and enable Google Drive APIs
- Created a service account (and generated the Private key), since I will not ask the user to login, and I will use my space to manage the files
- Shared a folder on my drive with the service account

Now my problem is that all google's libraries for many platforms (Java, Node, Pyhthon...) help the developer setup the classic Google Signin to retrieve the **user's access token** and make calls to the API, working with the user space.
I haven't found any library for service accounts, the only way retrieve the access token seems to be folliwing [these google steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest)
Which consists in manually generating the JWT (every time it expires) and manually calling the OAuth to get the access token (every time it expires)

My question is: is there a simpler procedure like a library to handle this manual process of refreshing JWTs and access tokens or an "already authorized api key" to make calls to Drive APIs like with Drive Geocoding API?

I am also accepting advices, since I dont really know if including the private key file to generate the JWT on the React Native client is a best practice. How should I handle it?